# Search Account by Id

Tags: soql

This is really simple but I can't figure out why it's not working

I'm trying to get the Account Name from Id

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = "001d000001xxxxxxxx"
```

If I run this in the force developer console it says 'Unknown error parsing query'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Single quotes will work.

> Any set of characters surrounded by single quotes. For example,
>   String s = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
>   String size: Strings have no limit on the number of characters they can include. Instead, the heap size limit is used to ensure that your Apex programs don't grow too large.
>
> Empty Strings and Trailing Whitespace: sObject String field values follow the same rules as in the SOAP API: they can never be empty (only null), and they can never include leading and trailing whitespace. These conventions are necessary for database storage.

[SF APEX Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the Id in single quote (') instead of double quotes (")